# ERROR in ./src/auth/AuthService.js Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:16)

Tags: vuejs2, auth0, es6-class, webpack-4

I have setup vuejs with webpack 4 and it's working fine now I have added auth0 file in my vuejs application and include it into the login page view It may be a webpack issue as in console the export default not working. Whenever I tried to work with vue-cli it works fine as well in the example. I want it with a webpack 4.

```
ERROR in ./src/auth/AuthService.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| export default class AuthService {
|   authenticated = this.isAuthenticated()
|   authNotifier = new EventEmitter()
| 
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/views/session/Login.vue 59:0-49
 @ ./src/views/session/Login.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 babel-polyfill ./src/index.js
```

This is my login vue file.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Auth0 - Vue</a>

          <router-link :to="'/'"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-margin">
              Home
          </router-link>

          <button
            class="btn btn-primary btn-margin"
            v-if="!authenticated"
            @click="login()">
              Log In
          </button>

          <button
            class="btn btn-primary btn-margin"
            v-if="authenticated"
            @click="logout()">
              Log Out
          </button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <router-view 
        :auth="auth" 
        :authenticated="authenticated">
      </router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AuthService from './auth/AuthService'

const auth = new AuthService()

const { login, logout, authenticated, authNotifier } = auth

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    authNotifier.on('authChange', authState => {
      this.authenticated = authState.authenticated
    })
    return {
      auth,
      authenticated
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login,
    logout
  }
}
</script>

<style>
@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

.btn-margin {
  margin-top: 7px
}
</style>
```

And this is my webpack config file.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require('webpack');

// plugins
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

// the path(s) that should be cleaned
let pathsToClean = [
    'dist'
]

// the clean options to use
let cleanOptions = {
    root: __dirname,
    verbose: false, // Write logs to console.
    dry: false
}

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
const publicPath = '/';

// Make sure any symlinks in the project folder are resolved:
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

function resolve(dir) {
    return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
    entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/index.js"],
    output: {
        // The build folder.
        path: resolveApp('dist'),
        // Generated JS file names (with nested folders).
        // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
        // We don't currently advertise code splitting but Webpack supports it.
        filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
        chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
        // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
        publicPath: publicPath
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        },
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: false,
        compress: true,
        port: 8080 // port number
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                enforce: 'pre',
                include: [resolve('src')],
                options: {
                    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: { minimize: true }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: 'static/img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: 'media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: 'media/fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(pathsToClean, cleanOptions),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./index.html",
            filename: "./index.html",
            favicon: './static/favicon.png'
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: 'static/img',
            to: 'static/img'
        }]),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css",
            chunkFilename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css"
        }),
        //jquery plugin
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your webpack config? Looks like babel-loader is not configured properly.

Comment: #ittus I have added my webpack config file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and I resolved it translating AuthService.js Module in Babel:
https://babeljs.io/repl

However, is not the solution that everybody want, so, you can try:

[Unable to load stage-3 javascript file using babel-loader from webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728054/unable-to-load-stage-3-javascript-file-using-babel-loader-from-webpack)

I do not resolved with this solution.